# Joining tables(in the domain classes) that don't have foreign key constraints defined explicitly

Tags: hibernate, grails

I am trying to create domain classes from(for) two tables(A & B) that don't have any foreign key constraints defined explicitly on the tables. But, there are columns in these tables that can be joined. I want to join these tables on these columns to GET the data. Since these are legacy tables I can't modify them. These tables have composite primary keys that I am using in the domain classes. How to join these tables on selected columns in the domain classes?

I also have cases where I need to join more than two tables that don't have foreign key constraints defined explicitly, but can be joined. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Foreign key, should be helpful in term of performance and logic inside your database system.

For Java code, you can use:

`@ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name = "table1.columnA", referencedColumnName = "table2.columnA")`

I use a `@ManyToOne` because you didn't give some information about relationship.

If you provide us other details, we could provide right code.

Answer (score -2):

Foreign key constraints are irrelevant. If the data is there, you can do the join/map the relationship.

Comment: I am new to Grails. Could you give me a simple example? thanks

Comment: Actually, no. I don't know Grails at all :) I was just talking about Hibernate's capabilities. Sorry.

Comment: Again with the downvote! What's the deal? If you have a problem with the answer, please explain it or provide a better.

Comment: I didn't cast the downvote.  I know how to join tables and I have several years of database design experience. I would like to know how to do the table joins in Grails(on selected columns using OnetoOne,OnetoMany, hasMApped, etc.) thanks.

Comment: If it's just mappings you need help with, I'd recommend you try a new question (or give this one a makeover). Don't emphasize the lack of constraints so much. Just show some table structures and examples of the code you're trying to map, and ask for help with the mappings. I'm sorry I can't help you with the Grails syntax.